# how to change the every value of attribute use eq() jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey guys i have a little problem when try to using eq() method in jquery.

i have an array like this

```
data = [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
```

and in my html code i have some input tags with this detail

```
<input type="text" value="1" name="sku[sku_id][quantity]">
<input type="text" value="1" name="sku[sku_id][quantity]">
<input type="text" value="1" name="sku[sku_id][quantity]">
<input type="text" value="1" name="sku[sku_id][quantity]">
<input type="text" value="1" name="sku[sku_id][quantity]">
```

and i want to change every value of my input tags, like this

```
<input type="text" value="1" name="sku[11][quantity]">
.
.
.
<input type="text" value="1" name="sku[15][quantity]">
```

i use this code in my script, but it's not working

```
$.each(data, function(key, value){
    var sku_id = value;
    console.log(key+" "+sku_id);
    $('input[name="sku[sku_id][quantity]"]').eq(key).attr('name', 'sku['+sku_id+'][quantity]');
})
```

but when i try to just add class in this like this, it working

```
$.each(data, function(key, value){
    var sku_id = value;
    console.log(key+" "+sku_id);
    $('input[name="sku[sku_id][quantity]"]').eq(key).addClass('goods');
})
```

anyone can help me please ? T^T

Comment: Instead of `eq()`, iterate over `input`s and use index. [See this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/fLwahk2f/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue comes because you are changing the `name` property itself which you are used to select in jquery selector.

so just use a `class` and check whether it works or not

please check this fiddle

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Lcbzv4hf/)